# Can this sound be created without electronic means?

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, synthesizer, audacity, waveform

I'm currently developing a game for which I'll need quite a few sound effects. I found Pixabay to attempt to get royalty free sounds, but although some are great, I'm not quite happy with all and would consider making my own if I get stuck and can't find a sound I'm satisfied with.

I've seen some videos of people creating sound effects, such as a standard sword slash which could be made with a leather purse and a knife sharpener, but for [sound effects such as this one](https://pixabay.com/sound-effects/samurai-slash-6845/) is it possible to procure everyday elements and objects to create it? Would this type of sound require synthesizers or some form of electronics involvement?

Normally I've used both Audacity and Waveform to mix some of the sounds I find, though in Audacity I've mostly only done pitch/speed/tempo change, fade outs/ins, and volume change, and in Waveform I've only dealt with sounds from a virtual instrument library which I record using my computer keyboard.

If anyone could please attempt to recreate the sound, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds electronically created, or at the very least augmented, like a descendant of some classic anime sound effects, with more punch.

Here's a great tutorial on that topic:

Comment: pretty cool! I'll look into this

Answer (score 0):

The sound effect in the link could easily be recreated using either a drum machine snare hit or a snare drum sample. Using Audacity or whatever DAW, you could then manipulate the sample.

You would probably want to stretch out the  snare sample, pitch it up using an LFO to get that rising sound, add some distortion for that gritty sound.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create that without electronics, as one feature of the sound is pitch (moore accurately, frequency or "speed") manipulation.

It's a noise sweep with a low frequency component, possibly a simple snare or splash cymbal created with noise and an underlying simple kick. It's a beat with the pitch being effected either by hand on a turntable, or via a pitch effect processor.

You could recreate this digitally with pitch effects on a retro 8-bit style beat (or make the beat yourself very easily with filtered noise bursts), or by playing an 8-bit style beat on a turntable and affecting the pitch by hand on a splash-cymbal + kick bit.

**Note:** it does have a grainy artefact effect, which leads me to believe the pitch manipulation is digitally recreated. There's also some clipping distortion crackling away.